# Изменение значения TextView из MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать данные из MainActivity на TextView, который находиться на одном из фрагментов при использовании

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fl_content"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать bundle. Посылаем текст:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

получаем стринг и сетим его в дальше в виджет:

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
```

можно кроме текста отправить и числа и всякое разное. [Вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) по Bundle

Comment: Да, спасибо, все работает. Только теперь новая проблема. При каждом нажатии на меню фрагмент заново создаётся, от этого как-то можно уйти? У меня допустим стоит там таймер, и при каждом нажатии он запускается заново.

Comment: сомневаюсь что можно уйти, но можно сохранять значение таймера и все будет нормально работать)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него